# Does .Net Maui have to clear the GraphicsView on Invalidate()?

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I'm using Maui's GraphicsView with AbsoluteLayout and it always clears the view's canvas entirely when I invalidate the view.

I read every bit of documentation I could find on the web, but I don't see any way to invalidate a GraphicsView without it's canvas being cleared.

I expected Invalidate() to force Draw() to be called, but for the view's canvas to be intact so it could be modified. I did not expect to have to redraw the entire canvas every time I invalidate the view.

Does anyone know if it's possible to force a redraw over the existing view without it clearing it's canvas?

If there's no way to do this I'll look at SkiaSharp as a possible alternative.

Comment: I mean is it not what the documentation says it would do? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/graphicsview?view=net-maui-8.0#invalidate-the-canvas, Also Skia does the same thing, I have made a lot of controls in it and you need to redraw everything when you invalidate.

Comment: If you're worried about performance, you can burn-in your Draw operations into a canvas buffer so that an Invalidate only needs to repaint that buffer and not repeat all the operations.

Comment: @StephenQuan If you can add a demo of this it would help them I suppose

Answer (score 0):

With `GraphicsView` itself, the OnDraw will draw on top of whatever's underneath. So there is an implicit clearing but that's not the canvas, but the application window itself. One way to see this is if you put two `GraphicsView` on top of each other, and you invalidate the 2nd/top one, the content of the 1st/bottom one isn't redrawn. You can use this multiple-`GraphicsView` method to partition background low-frequency Draw operations from high-frequency Draw operations into their respective `GraphicsView`. You can also use DrawImage to render an Image, but, .NET MAUI has limited operations for you to use that image as a buffered-backing store.

This is where `SkiaSharp` can help. Because its `SKBitmap` can receive draw operations via a `SKBitmapCanvas`. With this technique you can incrementally stack draw operations into your `SKBitmap` and render that to a `SKCanvasView` whenever you need. Here, `SKCanvasView` would be a substitute for `GraphicsView`.

To use SkiaSharp add NuGet packages `SkiaSharp.Views.Maui.Controls` and `SkiaSharp.Views.Maui.Core`. Your csproj should have package references similar to the following.

```xml
<PackageReference Include="SkiaSharp.Views.Maui.Controls" Version="2.88.7" />
<PackageReference Include="SkiaSharp.Views.Maui.Core" Version="2.88.7" />
```

In the following example, we initialize a SKBitmap.

We have an IDispatchTimer that updates the SKBitmap and invalidates the SKCanvasView.

The SKCanvasView, whenever it receives a paint request just renders the SKBitmap.

This example demonstrates a method whereby the Draw operations accumulate.

```cpp
// MauiProgram.cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using SkiaSharp.Views.Maui.Controls.Hosting;
namespace MauiSkiaApp
{
    public static class MauiProgram
    {
        public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
        {
            var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
            builder
                .UseMauiApp<App>()
                .UseSkiaSharp()
                .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
                {
                    fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                    fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
                });
#if DEBUG
            builder.Logging.AddDebug();
#endif
            return builder.Build();
        }
    }
}
```

```xml
<!-- MainPage.xaml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:skia="clr-namespace:SkiaSharp.Views.Maui.Controls;assembly=SkiaSharp.Views.Maui.Controls"
             x:Class="MauiSkiaApp.MainPage">
    <Grid>
        <skia:SKCanvasView x:Name="skiaView" PaintSurface="OnPaintSurface" SizeChanged="OnSizeChanged"/>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

```cs
// MainPage.xaml.cs
using SkiaSharp;
using SkiaSharp.Views.Maui;

namespace MauiSkiaApp;

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    SKBitmap? bitmap = null;
    Random rnd = new Random();
    IDispatcherTimer timer;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timer = Dispatcher.CreateTimer();
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10);
        timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
        timer.Start();
    }

    private void Timer_Tick(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (bitmap != null)
        {
            using (SKCanvas bitmapCanvas = new SKCanvas(bitmap))
            {
                int x1 = rnd.Next(bitmap.Width);
                int y1 = rnd.Next(bitmap.Height);
                int x2 = rnd.Next(bitmap.Width);
                int y2 = rnd.Next(bitmap.Height);
                bitmapCanvas.DrawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, new SKPaint() { Color = SKColors.Blue });
            }
            skiaView.InvalidateSurface();
        }
    }

    private void OnPaintSurface(object sender, SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs e)
    {
        if (bitmap == null)
        {
            bitmap = new SKBitmap(e.Info.Width, e.Info.Height);
        }
        var surface = e.Surface;
        var canvas = surface.Canvas;
        canvas.DrawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0);
    }

    private void OnSizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bitmap = null;
    }
}
```

[image: DrawLines.gif]

References:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/skiasharp?view=skiasharp-2.88
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/bitmaps/drawing

Comment: Thank you Stephen Quan. I did try SkiaSharp and found it behaved as I expected, so that's the way forward for me. Interesting info though re the layers of GraphicsView you describe. Thanks

Comment: Please accept the reply as answered if it is useful for you so that it will help others who have similar problems.:)