MAUI app has too many PathF points, possibly
Afternoon SO.
I've been playing around with Maui, after having not touched Xamarin for many years.
The issue I am having is with time taken to draw PathF elements to a canvas... i think
So, I have an Image and Canvas element on my front end.
In the backend I have an IDrawable that is called at timer increments.
I could not force the StrokeColour to take a gradient (with my knowledge) so opted for conditional adding of PathF elements to the canvas, depending on an incrementing value.
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Shapes;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace KeepYourFeet.Drawables
{
public class Route : IDrawable
{
    private Color colour;
    private double distance;
    private bool drawOverride;

    public Route(Color col, double dis)
    {
        colour = col;
        distance = dis * 1.725;
        drawOverride = false;
    }
    public Route(Color col, double dis, bool draw)
    {
        colour = col;
        distance = dis * 1.725;
        drawOverride = draw;
    }

    public void Draw(ICanvas canvas, RectF dirtyRect)
    {
        PathF path = new PathF();

        #region Create Journey
        if (0 == distance || (0 < distance && drawOverride)) path.MoveTo((float)422.00, (float)85.00);
        if (1 == distance || (1 < distance && drawOverride)) path.LineTo((float)422.48, (float)86.00);
        if (2 == distance || (2 < distance && drawOverride)) path.LineTo((float)422.95, (float)87.00);
        if (3 == distance || (3 < distance && drawOverride)) path.LineTo((float)423.43, (float)88.00);
        if (4 == distance || (4 < distance && drawOverride)) path.LineTo((float)423.90, (float)89.00);
        // AND SO ON
        if (2327 == distance || (2327 < distance && drawOverride)) path.LineTo((float)1711.00, (float)951.00);
        #endregion

        canvas.StrokeColor = colour;
        canvas.StrokeSize = 5;
        canvas.DrawPath(path);
    }
}
}

As seen, I ended up with 2327 elements and the processing seems to be killing off my app.
I cannot think of a better way to draw the tiny lines to screen incrementally using such small increases.
The calling code does not call Canvas.Invalidate() so I assume it is primarily the vast number of statements causing my issues.
Any guidance (other than "this is dumb") would be appreciated.
Here is the front end
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="KeepYourFeet.MapPage"
         Shell.TitleColor="Silver"
         Shell.BackgroundColor="Black"
         Title="Journey"
         BackgroundColor="Black">

<Frame
    WidthRequest="2402"
    HeightRequest="1156">
    <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
        <PanGestureRecognizer PanUpdated="PanGestureRecognizer_PanUpdated"/>
    </Frame.GestureRecognizers>

    <Grid
        WidthRequest="2402"
        HeightRequest="1156">

        <Image
            x:Name="actualMap"
            Source="small_earth.png"
            Aspect="Fill"
            WidthRequest="2402"
            HeightRequest="1156"
            ZIndex="0000">
        </Image>

        <GraphicsView
            x:Name="routeMap"
            WidthRequest="2402"
            HeightRequest="1156"
            BackgroundColor="Transparent"
            ZIndex="8888">
            <GraphicsView.GestureRecognizers>
                <PanGestureRecognizer PanUpdated="PanGestureRecognizer_PanUpdated"/>
            </GraphicsView.GestureRecognizers>

        </GraphicsView>

    </Grid>

</Frame>

</ContentPage>

and a portion of the backend
using KeepYourFeet.Database;
using KeepYourFeet.Database.Models;
using KeepYourFeet.Drawables;
using KeepYourFeet.GPS;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Shapes;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace KeepYourFeet;

public partial class MapPage : ContentPage
{
private double xOffset;
private double yOffset;
private double currentScale;
private double startScale;
private double distanceTotal = 1350;
private double distanceMiles;
private GPSLocation gpsLocation;
private IDispatcherTimer timer;
private Location? prevLocation;
private DataAccessLayer DAL;
private double index = 0;

public MapPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

#if ANDROID
    {
        Android.App.Activity? currAct = ActivityStateManager.Default.GetCurrentActivity();
        if (currAct != null) { currAct.RequestedOrientation = Android.Content.PM.ScreenOrientation.Portrait; }
    }
#endif

    DAL = new DataAccessLayer();
    gpsLocation = new GPSLocation();

    //GetPreviousLocation(); <-- DONT WANT OLD LOCATION...
    QueryCurrent();       // <-- WE WANT TO SAVE NEW STARTING LOCATION!
    GetDistance();
    DrawRoute(distanceMiles, true);

    xOffset = 0;
    yOffset = 0;
    currentScale = 1;
    startScale = 1;

    timer = Dispatcher.CreateTimer();
    timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
    timer.Tick += QueryLocation;
    timer.Start();
}

private void PanGestureRecognizer_PanUpdated(object sender, PanUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.StatusType)
    {
        case GestureStatus.Running:
            // Translate and pan.
            double boundsX = (Content.Width / 2) - (Window.Width / 2.5);
            double boundsY = (Content.Height / 2) - (Window.Height / 2.5);

            Content.TranslationX = Math.Clamp(xOffset + e.TotalX, -boundsX, boundsX);
            Content.TranslationY = Math.Clamp(yOffset + e.TotalY, -boundsY, boundsY);

            break;

        case GestureStatus.Completed:
            // Store the translation applied during the pan
            xOffset = Content.TranslationX;
            yOffset = Content.TranslationY;

            break;
    }
}

private void QueryCurrent(bool drawFresh = false)
{
    Location? location = gpsLocation.GetCurrentLocation();
    if (location != null)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("#KYF Location != null");
        // STORE LOCATION
        PositionLog newLog = new PositionLog()
        {
            Id = (prevLocation != null ? 1 : 0),
            Latitude = location.Latitude,
            Longtitude = location.Longitude
        };
        _ = DAL.InsertNewPositionLog(newLog);

        // PROCESS DISTANCE
        if (prevLocation != null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("#KYF prevLocation != null");
            distanceMiles += Location.CalculateDistance(prevLocation, location, DistanceUnits.Miles);
            _ = DAL.UpdateDistance(distanceMiles);

            // UPDATE MAP
            //DrawRoute(distanceMiles, drawFresh);
            Debug.WriteLine("#KYF index: {0}", ++index);
            DrawRoute(index, drawFresh);
        }
        prevLocation = location;
    }
    else Debug.WriteLine("#KYF Location == null");

}

private void QueryLocation(object? sender, EventArgs? e)
{
    QueryCurrent();
}

private void GetDistance()
{
    Task<Distance?> getDistanceTask = Task.Run(() => DAL.GetDistance());
    getDistanceTask.Wait();
    distanceMiles = (getDistanceTask.Result != null) ? getDistanceTask.Result.MilesTraveled : 0;
}

private void DrawRoute(double distance, bool drawFresh)
{
    //routeMap.Invalidate();

    Route route = new Route(Color.FromRgb(255, 0, 0), distance, drawFresh);

    routeMap.Drawable = route;
}
}


Do you just want to draw a gradient line?

The problem with GraphicsView is we cannot creating a backing Bitmap that we can incrementally update. Instead, consider using SKCanvasView/SKBitmap from SkiaSharp. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/77857948/881441

Cheers Stephen.
I had previously seen mention of SkiaSharp - but assumed it was a third party library and so avoided it in favour of libraries I had already found.

Seems you have solved the question. If you want to use SkiaSharp, you may also refer to  the official doc SkiaSharp Graphics in Xamarin.Forms, .NET MAUI - SkiaSharp.

Actually, the issue persists - but in another form now.

If you have another question, you may raise a new thread on StackOverflow to let more people know and help.

It turns out ICanvas on GraphicsView.Drawable does work!
The issue with my code was that I had hastily called a Task without a Run().
_ = Task.Run(() => DAL.UpdateDistance(distanceMiles));

The system now runs okay.
I now plan on putting the slowest part, "GetCurrentLocation()", into a separate thread and update the view upon changes.
